# I was adding the custom CSS & JS using hooks and there was this error even I didn't touch the wp-class-hook

Tags: errors

**Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'skfans_wp_enqueue_script()' not found or invalid function name in C:\xampp\htdocs\plugin\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 306:**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','skfans_wp_enqueue_script()'); 
    function skfans_wp_enqueue_script() {
        wp_enqueue_style('skfans_dev_plugin', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)."assets/css/style.css");
        wp_enqueue_script('skfans_dev_script',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)."assets/js/custom.js",true);
    }
```

Comment: Callbacks are without `()`

Comment: new to plugin development, could you please tell me where is the callbacks here?

Comment: You can check the wordpress documentation about [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) to understand how to work with them

Answer (score 2):

The text in the second parameter is not code to run, it is the *name* of a function. That is why it does not and cannot work. **The warning is PHP telling you that no function with that name exists.** Or more specifically that is it an invalid function name.

A function with `()` in its name is not possible. For your code to work you would need a function named `skfans_wp_enqueue_script()` but that's impossible because it would mean your function looks like this:

```php
function skfans_wp_enqueue_script()() {
```

This would generate syntax errors and crash immediately.

To clarify the difference, this is what you believed it meant:

```php
add_action('action/event name', 'run this PHP code inside these quotes when action/event happens');
```

What it actually means:

```php
add_action('action/event name', 'A thing to call when the action/event happens' );
```

e.g.

```php
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpdocs_my_save_post' );
function wpdocs_my_save_post() {
    // .....
```

Further reading:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/